# How can I remove legend from the figure in seaborn?

Tags: python, visualization, matplotlib, seaborn, plotly

Here is my diagrams,
[image]

I want to remove the labels of the second bar that is C1,C2,C3,C4,C5, because it is repeating.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
plt.gca().legend.set_visible(False)
```

or

```
plt.gca().legend.remove()
```

I think.